# Jquery autocomplete code works with old version of Jquery, but not later versions

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have been using Jquery autocomplete successfully in the past. Recently, I upgraded to new versions of jquery and jquery ui, and I am getting errors with the same code.

Working versions: jquery 1.8.2, jquery ui 1.8.24
Failing versions: jquery 1.10.2, jquery ui 1.11.4

Following is the Jquery autocomplete code:

```
    $('#lakeId').autocomplete({
        delay: 1000,
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("getLakes","BuoyJS")',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.lakeId, value: item.lakeId };
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
    });
```

When it fails, I get a message indicating that a function is not found in the response $.map statement after a successful return from the server. Here is a view of what comes back from the server (from Firebug):

Following is the JSON string that was returned to the browser for parsing.  I got this from Firebug by selecting the responseText argument.

"[{"lakeId":"M: Maranacook Lake"},{"lakeId":"MH: Moosehead Lake"},{"lakeId":"MOUSAM: Mousam Lake"},{"lakeId":"MS: Messalonskee Lake"},{"lakeId":"MSLK: Mooselookmeguntic"}]"

Comment: use jQuerymigrate (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate) it provides backward compatibility

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem by gradually increasing the version of Jquery from 1.8 to 2.2.3, which is the latest version that Visual Studio 2015 Nuget offers.  I'm not sure what is different from last time, but it works now.